# sending hello world alert via andro phones using ionic 3 bluetooth,how

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth

I want to send a `hello world` alert text between two paired Android phones using ionic 3. I have two Android phones A and B connected via bluetooth and I have an ionic3 app. If I send the `String` `helloworld` from phone A I'd like an alert dialogue to appear on phone B reading `phone A says hello!`. Is there any example app for this functionality?

I get the error:

> ```
> unable to connect device
> ```

Here are the versions:

```
>> cordova -v             >>>>>>>>>>>>>
cordova version: 6.5.0
>> cordova plugin list     >>>>>>>>>>>>>
com.tomvanenckevort.cordova.bluetoothserial 0.2.3 "Bluetooth Serial"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.16 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

Comment: @Akshay Dwivedi  my topic is deleted , I dont know why. anyway, I am afraid, cordova plugin add https://github.com/tomvanenckevort/BluetoothSerial this plugin is not working.  connect button does not work either. In ionic site, plugin , at least, connect  was woking. I dont know , what is the point still keeping int in site..

Comment: Do you already have code? When does the error occur? What's the expected and the actual outcome?

Comment: Hello Karl,
Do you already have code?  -> Yes,  full project  http://blog.turkalpkucur.com/sonversion.rar
 When does the error occur? ->when I press connect button, it gives error "unable to connect device"   in debug mode,error message:
unable to connect device
<Note:  debugging i3: https://medium.com/@leetheguy/the-best-way-to-debug-an-ionic-app-on-a-device-79833bef5d1d    > 
 What's the expected and the actual outcome? –>
 displaying "connection request" to other andro phone .After connection,second expected outcome  is sending hello to other phone
actual outcome:giveserror

Comment: I think you could not be able to solve it.